# Auto delete certain rows on the first of every month - Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-custom-function

I've built a Sheet on Google Sheets with multiple tabs and formulas for me and my coworkers to use.
Only thing I couldn't do is set a formula that deletes multiple specific custom cells on multiple specific custom tabs on the first day of every month.
What script do I need to add here? Consider the fact I need to add to the function the cells and columns that will be deleted on the first of every month?

The cells that I want the function to erase are not a funcion themselves, they are empty cells which me and my colleagues fill manually twice a month, I need the fuction to erase the values which we add manually, and I need it to do that every first of every month.

Thanks

Comment: Hi, welcome to WebApps. Would you please edit your question to describe how many unique custom functions are there? Would you please explain whether the custom functions reference parameters described in the cell (such as `=DOUBLE(100)`), or do they reference cells containing parameter values (such as `DOUBLE(A1)` where Cell A1=100). Would you also describe what you have tried to solve the problem yourself.

Comment: hi, I added to my question the details you requested. Regarding how I tried to solve the problem myself, I am not a programmer so I can't write JaveScript

Comment: _ I am not a programmer so I can't write JavaScript_ OK, but how were you going to develop the custom functions - they're written in apps script (a version of JavaScript).

Comment: I was hoping theres' a relatively easy function I can implement in my Google Sheets document. I can't write it though.

Comment: So, you've got a bunch of custom functions; each relies on values entered in one or more referenced cells, Once a month, you want to delete the values in the referenced cells so that you can start over. You think that this requires a script but you're not sure about the details because you're not a programmer. You don't describe the sheets, the custom functions or the referenced cells. But you want to know "What script do I need to add here?" What kind of answer do you expect given that you aren't a programmer, and you won't know how to write the script?

Comment: _I was hoping theres' a relatively easy function _ Nope.

Comment: Google sheets has two types of function. #1: The built-in functions - there is a list [here](https://support.google.com/docs/table/25273). #2: Functions (programs, if you will) that are written in apps script (a sub-set of JavaScript). To learn scripting, start with the [Overview](https://www.google.com/script/start/), and the [Guide to Automating Tasks with Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/samples).